# mount: special device /dev/sda1 does not exist

Tags: linux, centos, mount, fdisk

I had a `CentOS 6` server suddenly lock up on me after doing about 2 weeks of calculations for a project. Upon reboot, the machine would crash while attempting to mount the devices listed in the `fstab` with the following error:

`mount: special device /dev/sda1 does not exist`

I was able to remount the filesystem and comment out that line in the `fstab` but I really need to get to that data.  Here are a few outputs that I notice other questioners need to give but alas all of the answers to their problems have yet to fix mine.

fdisk:

```
fdisk -l /dev/sda
Disk /dev/sda: 4000.8 GB, 4000787030016 bytes
15 heads, 3 sectors/track, 173645270 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 45 * 512 = 23040 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x965711d3

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1    95443717  2147483631   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

blkid:

```
/dev/mapper/vg_bioprocessor2-lv_root: UUID="6b345de4-041e-4e42-ac36-2da09227833b" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sda: UUID="Intel   ^P" TYPE="ddf_raid_member"
/dev/sdc: TYPE="isw_raid_member"
/dev/md126p1: UUID="511977e8-3dc7-47a0-af63-59358bc6a446" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/md126p2: UUID="X1Cfv2-bDTF-JHy2-fTS5-jHNv-zubC-GXRq5e" TYPE="LVM2_member"
/dev/mapper/vg_bioprocessor2-lv_swap: UUID="5c049cea-a966-419d-a454-a0cdf151d067" TYPE="swap"
/dev/mapper/vg_bioprocessor2-lv_home: UUID="1a1b3a99-da29-4aa6-a5ac-aa0b7769a5e2" TYPE="ext4"
```

fstab:

```
#
# /etc/fstab
# Created by anaconda on Fri Mar 14 07:11:41 2014
#
# Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk'
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info
#
/dev/mapper/vg_bioprocessor2-lv_root /                       ext4    defaults        1 1
UUID=511977e8-3dc7-47a0-af63-59358bc6a446 /boot                   ext4    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/vg_bioprocessor2-lv_home /home                   ext4    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/vg_bioprocessor2-lv_swap swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults        0 0
devpts                  /dev/pts                devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0 0
sysfs                   /sys                    sysfs   defaults        0 0
proc                    /proc                   proc    defaults        0 0
/dev/sda1       /mnt/Scratch    ext4    defaults        1       2
```

One thing that might be causing issues is the fact that `blkid` is stating that `/dev/sda` is a `ddf_raid_member` when it is not. However I am not sure if that is the root cause of this issue or not.

Comment: Haven't you mounted the `/dev/sda1` on `/mnt/Scratch`. if yes then cd to mount point. What file are you able to see?

Comment: Try to run this command `mdadm --detail /dev/md0` I guess that you have a broken `Raid`